# Writing a Unix installer for a Jar file

Tags: java, unix, jar, makefile, executable-jar

I have written a Java application, and I have created an executable Jar file that successfully runs my application with `java -jar myJar.jar`.  I have an executable shell script called `launchMyProgram` that wraps the launching of this Jar (and offers various flags like --help etc.).  My target output directory looks like this:

```
$ ls /path/to/MyProject/target/
archive-tmp/      classes/          myJar.jar
```

What is the standard method for me to write an installer for my Unix-only application?  I assume that I would be correct to drop the `launchMyProgram` executable in /usr/local/bin.  But where do I put the Jar file?  Should I make my own subdirectory somewhere for my program's files?  Do I need to copy the `classes` directory from the above output into the same directory as the Jar?  This will run via a Makefile so of course users may override my choices.

Basically, I want a user to be able to run `make && make install`, and be able to run my application with `launchMyProgram`, and I want place my files (one jar, a 'classes' folder, and a shell script) in the most typical places possible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to do it has been reinvented many times but is unfortunately not yet standard.

Since a JAR is a ZIP file which is allowed to have an arbitrary prefix, you can prepend a launcher shell script to your jar, mark it executable, and treat that as a standalone binary.

```
$ echo '#!/bin/bash' > launchMyProgram
$ echo 'exec java -cp "${0}" com.example.program.Main "${@}"' >> launchMyProgram
$ cat myJar.jar >> launchMyProgram
$ chmod +x ./launchMyProgram
$ ./launchMyProgram
Hello, world!
```

See [Simple & Easy Executable Jars](http://mesosphere.io/2013/12/07/executable-jars/) for more details.

You should be able to pack everything in the `classes/` folder into your jar and still have things work.

---

Also, if you want to provide RPMs or DEB packages or something for users, [`fpm`](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) makes that really easy.